# Upload an image with reactjs and mongodb not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, file-upload, react-hook-form

I'm trying to upload a picture(using react-hook-form) to my MongoDB database. But it's stored all of my data on database except images data. I have mentioned frontend code and backend API bellow, please have a look.

**1. Frontend react-use-form**

```
const { register,handleSubmit,errors } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => {
    const demo = data;
    console.log("data from react hook form", demo)

    fetch('http://localhost:4200/demotest', {   
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(demo)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Successfull', data);
        })
};

return (
    <Container>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <form className="ship-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <h1>Field Array </h1>
                    <p>The following demo allow you to delete, append, prepend items</p> 
                    <input ref={register} type="file" name="image" />
                    <input name="name" ref={register({ required: true })} placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    {errors.name && <span>This field is required</span>}
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
);
```

[Please have a look on my console log files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32tfg.png)

**2. Backend Api**

```
        app.post('/demotest', (req, res) => {
        const profile = req.body;
        client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        client.connect(err => {
            const collection = client.db("TeachersProfile").collection("demoTest");
            collection.insert(profile, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.status(500).send({ message: err });
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result.ops[0]);
                }
            });
            client.close();
        });
    });
```

[and that's my database output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kqJc.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that you're getting a File object from the browser (the image file), and then you're using `JSON.stringify` on the form data (which includes the File) and getting `{}` stored in the database. This is expected behavior. The File object doesn't have its own enumerable properties. `JSON.stringify()` only includes enumerable properties.

Typically when dealing with user supplied files (such as images), one option is to simply take their supplied file, place an identifier in the database that will help you find it later, and then store the file outside of the database. For example, an alternative solution for you would be to generate a random, unique filename for the image and store the image as-is with the filename in a storage service such as [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) or [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html). You would also need to store the unique filename you generated in your MongoDB document so you can retrieve the file later. If you really want to use MongoDB to store your images, I suggest you take a look at [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).